# How hard Is to add Iphone OS 3.0 features to an openGL game

Tags: cocoa-touch, opengl, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm programming this game in OpenGL, mostly working inside an single EAGLView (I'm not that familiar with Views and other Cocoa concepts, my work to this point only involved using OpenGL to draw my game and calculating the logic myself).

I'm being told for adding a ton of features:

- Send mails to Your friends when You achieve certain objectives in the game.
- Interact with facebook ( I'm being told that I will provided with all the libraries I need).
- Interaction with store kit !, buy weapons, Items, etc..

I would like to know, how effort and time will take to add those features... It's complicated to use GameKit ..StoreKit..MediaPlayer and other frameworks ?, considering that I only have worked with OpenGL to this point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not hard to add those features.

Longer answer: depending on your background, if object-oriented concepts are new to you, it may take you longer to learn how to use the objects and frameworks. The only thing you can really do is read over the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) and look at tutorials and decide how complicated it looks.  Really, though, it's all well designed and thought out and if you have a programming background, a couple of the examples should give you plenty to start with and you'll get it all soon.  And then come on back with your specific questions and smarter devs than I will answer them.

The hard part is all the details: weapons, items, etc.